# Reload redux on save

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-redux, react-hooks

I am working on a React.JS project, based on the `react-boilerplate` templates. Unfortunately, `react-boilerplate` only has an example of loading remote data into redux. There is no save example.

I was able to write the `save` actions, reducer and saga, no problem. It is all pretty standard stuff. However, one issue holding me back, which I was unable to resolve - reloading the store after saving.

I did the below:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    loadEvent: eventId => dispatch(loadEvent(eventId)),
    saveEvent: values => {
      const event = dispatch(saveEvent(values))
      return dispatch(loadEvent(event.id || values.id))
    }
  }
}
```

I want the above code to work as a promise - reload the event by id after save finished to completion.

It is not working like I need it to. I get load invoked, yet there is no new data in the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by sticking everything inside my saga as below:

```
try {
  // Call our request helper (see 'utils/request')
  const createdEvent = yield call(request, requestURL, {
    method: !isNaN(id) && id !== undefined && id !== null ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(event)
  })
  yield put(eventLoaded(createdEvent, id))
  yield put(loadEvent(createdEvent['id']))
} catch (err) {
  yield put(eventLoadingError(err))
}
```

Now, the thing works as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

You should create some `xxxx_REQUEST` and `xxxx_SUCCESS|FAILURE` action `types` to each request (not important it is saving or not).
I don't know you are redux-saga or redux-thunk but after your request fetch finished, you should dispatch `xxxx_SUCCESS|FAILURE` then in your reducer, get data and store it on you store.

Then you could use a selector to get data from redux store in your component.

Comment: I have actions. What do you dispatch in the reducer?

Comment: My action for loadEvent above is: ```export function loadEvent(id) {
  return {
    type: LOAD_EVENT,
    id
  }
}``` What do you suggest should the saveEvent() action be?

Comment: you should create `LOAD_EVENT_REQUEST` , and call api request within it, then based on api call response , dispatch `LOAD_EVENT_SUCCESS` or `LOAD_EVENT_FAILURE`